# Disposing of a texture with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to dispose of a texture after loading it in three.js.
I load it with

```
var tex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("image.png");
```

and it displays fine. But when I try:

```
tex.dispose();
```

I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispose'" every time.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/textures/Texture.js#L83

However, you might be using an older version of three.js that still used `deallocate()`..?

Comment: I downloaded this version a couple of weeks ago so I think it's the latest. At any rate "deallocate" does not wok either. But you're saying that "dispose" should work?

Comment: Yes, it should work. See updated answer. Is the 'tex' variable really a Texture?

Comment: Yeah i looked at the source and saw the dispose method is defined. I also tried 'tex.dispatchEvent({type: 'dispose'});' and I also get "... has no 'method dispatchEvent'". So I guess 'tex' isn't a texture... But I load it with 'loadTexture', and I set it as the 'map' property of a 'MeshLambertMaterial' and it displays ok... I'm stuck :(

Comment: Okay, I suck, it was a version problem. Redownloaded and it works fine (what the hell did I download the first time???). Anyways, thanks for your help willem!

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party on this one :) but I came across this post whilst trying to use the texture.dispose() method in ThreeJS with no luck.  Each time I changed a material on a plane in my scene, the overall texture count kept on rising causing IOS inparticular to crash on large textures.  The answer was to dispose of the Diffuse, Normal and Roughness maps on the Plane material first before then setting the new material.
`    private static UpdatePlaneMaterial(material: any) {
let plane: any = LayingPatternViewer.scene.getObjectById(LayingPatternViewer.horizontalPlaneId);

```
    if (plane) {
        plane.material.map.dispose();
        plane.material.normalMap.dispose();
        plane.material.roughnessMap.dispose();
        plane.material = material;
        this.Animate();
    }
}`
```